# How to disable Magento Recurring profiles and billing agreements?

Tags: magento

Is there an easy way (ex: using local.xml) to completely disable recurring profiles and billing agreements in Magento (v 1.7+)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The blocks are created and the links are added in:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml`

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml`

Normally i would recommend to remove the links afterwards, but the `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` doesn't have a removeLink method, so I think the only way is to copy the two xml files in your theme and remove the content. If you remove only the addLink node, the user has no link in the navigation in his login-area.

There are lots of extension which do this.

I implement my own one:
https://github.com/ikonoshirt/ExtendedAccountNavigation

Comment: I will have this task in a week or two too, if I find a better way I will update the answer :)

Comment: The free '[Frontend Links Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MagePsycho/extension/7905/frontend_links_manager)' extension lets you remove the links from the Customer Account list using the control panel.

Comment: I edited the answer and added my extension which I wrote for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

There is another way making this work.  Create a blank.xml file with  in it and add the following configuration to the app/etc/local.xml file.  This method requires no changes or layout file overrides.

```
<config>
        <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sales_billing_agreement>
                    <file>blank.xml</file>
                </sales_billing_agreement>
                <sales_recurring_profile>
                    <file>blank.xml</file>
                </sales_recurring_profile>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```